# Make longtable (in landscape mode) wider than textwidth

Tags: tables, longtable, koma-script, scaling, landscape

Assuming I have a table going over several pages

```
\documentclass[DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,longtable}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Create a very compact itemized list environment
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet, nosep, wide, 
                 leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
                 before=\vspace{-0.50\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

% keep scope of longtable-related instructions local to current TeX group
\begingroup 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <--- important
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}P{0.38}P{0.38}P{0.2}}

\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}\\ 
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{l}{(Table \ref{my-label}, cont'd)}\\ % re-state table number
\addlinespace
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{r}{(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\begin{mylist}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

%\addlinespace % omit if at page break

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\end{longtable}
\endgroup % end of TeX group that encases the 'longtable' material

\end{document}
```

Code Copy and pasted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414342/make-text-readable-in-table-needed-automatic-text-wrapping-in-list-like-enviro?answertab=votes#tab-top), thanks to [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico).

I want to orient the table in landscape mode. When I am using `begin{landscape}` with `\documentclass[DIV=8]{scrartcl}`, the problem I am facing is that the table is only as "long/deep" as my text width. That results on only two or three rows per page... Is there a way to tell latex to go over the text width with the table?

Comment: The KOMA addmargin environment won't help.  It just changes \leftskip and \rightskip.  You need to use the geometry package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` to increase the text area.  The `\rule` is just to demonstrate the space available.

```
\documentclass[DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,longtable}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Create a very compact itemized list environment
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet, nosep, wide, 
                 leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
                 before=\vspace{-0.50\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{lipsum}% mwe only
\begin{document}

% keep scope of longtable-related instructions local to current TeX group
\afterpage{%
\newgeometry{textwidth={\dimexpr \textwidth+2cm}}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\textheight}% show available space
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <--- important
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}P{0.38}P{0.38}P{0.2}}

\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}\\ 
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{l}{(Table \ref{my-label}, cont'd)}\\ % re-state table number
\addlinespace
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{r}{(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\begin{mylist}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

%\addlinespace % omit if at page break

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that works, but it takes the table out of the textflow. Now the table starts as if a `\pagebreak` was inserted before it. Is there a way to keep it within the text-flow? There is no need to do it necessarily in landscape. If I can make it wider than my text area, portrait is okay too.

Comment: Sorry, but both \newgeometry and landscape require a pagebreak (actually, a \clearpage) at the beginning and end.  You could use the afterpage package to flow around them.

Comment: This will also undermine KOMA's page layout, won't it? But maybe there's no way of avoiding that ...? I mean, `DIV=8` now does nothing? Or?

Comment: KOMA and geometry are supposed to be compatible.  Geometry accepts KOMA's peculiar layout as the default.

Comment: Is there a way to go wider than the text width in portrait mode?

Comment: If you leave the \newgeometry and throw out the landscape, I just did.  You can even use the KOMA addmargin (negative distance) for that.