# Multiple pages table – 100 rows x 10 columns

Tags: tables, longtable

How can I fit the following table on multiple pages? Landscape mode is also accepted.

```
\begin{tabular}{llllllllllll}
\toprule
{} & Money Market Euro & Bond Euro Short Term & Bond Euro Medium-Long Term & Global Bond Developed Markets & Corporate Bond High Yield & Emerging Markets Bond & Equity Europe & Equity North America & Equity Pacific & Equity Emerg Markets & Opportunities \\
\midrule
0.0   &              0.05 &                  0.2 &                       0.42 &                           0.2 &                      0.05 &                  0.08 &           0.0 &                  0.0 &            0.0 &                  0.0 &           0.0 \\
1.0   &            0.0495 &                0.198 &                     0.4158 &                         0.198 &                    0.0495 &                0.0792 &      0.001616 &             0.006453 &       0.000865 &             0.000566 &        0.0005 \\
2.0   &             0.049 &                0.196 &                     0.4116 &                         0.196 &                     0.049 &                0.0784 &      0.003231 &             0.012906 &       0.001731 &             0.001132 &         0.001 \\
3.0   &            0.0485 &                0.194 &                     0.4074 &                         0.194 &                    0.0485 &                0.0776 &      0.004847 &             0.019358 &       0.002596 &             0.001698 &        0.0015 \\
4.0   &             0.048 &                0.192 &                     0.4032 &                         0.192 &                     0.048 &                0.0768 &      0.006463 &             0.025811 &       0.003462 &             0.002264 &         0.002 \\
5.0   &            0.0475 &                 0.19 &                      0.399 &                          0.19 &                    0.0475 &                 0.076 &      0.008078 &             0.032264 &       0.004327 &             0.002831 &        0.0025 \\
6.0   &             0.047 &                0.188 &                     0.3948 &                         0.188 &                     0.047 &                0.0752 &      0.009694 &             0.038717 &       0.005193 &             0.003397 &         0.003 \\
7.0   &            0.0465 &                0.186 &                     0.3906 &                         0.186 &                    0.0465 &                0.0744 &      0.011309 &             0.045169 &       0.006058 &             0.003963 &        0.0035 \\
8.0   &             0.046 &                0.184 &                     0.3864 &                         0.184 &                     0.046 &                0.0736 &      0.012925 &             0.051622 &       0.006924 &             0.004529 &         0.004 \\
9.0   &            0.0455 &                0.182 &                     0.3822 &                         0.182 &                    0.0455 &                0.0728 &      0.014541 &             0.058075 &       0.007789 &             0.005095 &        0.0045 \\
10.0  &             0.045 &                 0.18 &                      0.378 &                          0.18 &                     0.045 &                 0.072 &      0.016156 &             0.064528 &       0.008655 &             0.005661 &         0.005 \\
11.0  &            0.0445 &                0.178 &                     0.3738 &                         0.178 &                    0.0445 &                0.0712 &      0.017772 &              0.07098 &        0.00952 &             0.006227 &        0.0055 \\
12.0  &             0.044 &                0.176 &                     0.3696 &                         0.176 &                     0.044 &                0.0704 &      0.019388 &             0.077433 &       0.010386 &             0.006793 &         0.006 \\
13.0  &            0.0435 &                0.174 &                     0.3654 &                         0.174 &                    0.0435 &                0.0696 &      0.021003 &             0.083886 &       0.011251 &              0.00736 &        0.0065 \\
14.0  &             0.043 &                0.172 &                     0.3612 &                         0.172 &                     0.043 &                0.0688 &      0.022619 &             0.090339 &       0.012117 &             0.007926 &         0.007 \\
15.0  &            0.0425 &                 0.17 &                      0.357 &                          0.17 &                    0.0425 &                 0.068 &      0.024235 &             0.096791 &       0.012982 &             0.008492 &        0.0075 \\
16.0  &             0.042 &                0.168 &                     0.3528 &                         0.168 &                     0.042 &                0.0672 &       0.02585 &             0.103244 &       0.013848 &             0.009058 &         0.008 \\
17.0  &            0.0415 &                0.166 &                     0.3486 &                         0.166 &                    0.0415 &                0.0664 &      0.027466 &             0.109697 &       0.014713 &             0.009624 &        0.0085 \\
18.0  &             0.041 &                0.164 &                     0.3444 &                         0.164 &                     0.041 &                0.0656 &      0.029082 &              0.11615 &       0.015579 &              0.01019 &         0.009 \\
19.0  &            0.0405 &                0.162 &                     0.3402 &                         0.162 &                    0.0405 &                0.0648 &      0.030697 &             0.122602 &       0.016444 &             0.010756 &        0.0095 \\
20.0  &              0.04 &                 0.16 &                      0.336 &                          0.16 &                      0.04 &                 0.064 &      0.032313 &             0.129055 &        0.01731 &             0.011322 &          0.01 \\
21.0  &            0.0395 &                0.158 &                     0.3318 &                         0.158 &                    0.0395 &                0.0632 &      0.033928 &             0.135508 &       0.018175 &             0.011888 &        0.0105 \\
22.0  &             0.039 &                0.156 &                     0.3276 &                         0.156 &                     0.039 &                0.0624 &      0.035544 &             0.141961 &       0.019041 &             0.012455 &         0.011 \\
23.0  &            0.0385 &                0.154 &                     0.3234 &                         0.154 &                    0.0385 &                0.0616 &       0.03716 &             0.148413 &       0.019906 &             0.013021 &        0.0115 \\
24.0  &             0.038 &                0.152 &                     0.3192 &                         0.152 &                     0.038 &                0.0608 &      0.038775 &             0.154866 &       0.020772 &             0.013587 &         0.012 \\
25.0  &            0.0375 &                 0.15 &                      0.315 &                          0.15 &                    0.0375 &                  0.06 &      0.040391 &             0.161319 &       0.021637 &             0.014153 &        0.0125 \\
26.0  &             0.037 &                0.148 &                     0.3108 &                         0.148 &                     0.037 &                0.0592 &      0.042007 &             0.167772 &       0.022503 &             0.014719 &         0.013 \\
27.0  &            0.0365 &                0.146 &                     0.3066 &                         0.146 &                    0.0365 &                0.0584 &      0.043622 &             0.174224 &       0.023368 &             0.015285 &        0.0135 \\
28.0  &             0.036 &                0.144 &                     0.3024 &                         0.144 &                     0.036 &                0.0576 &      0.045238 &             0.180677 &       0.024234 &             0.015851 &         0.014 \\
29.0  &            0.0355 &                0.142 &                     0.2982 &                         0.142 &                    0.0355 &                0.0568 &      0.046854 &              0.18713 &       0.025099 &             0.016417 &        0.0145 \\
30.0  &             0.035 &                 0.14 &                      0.294 &                          0.14 &                     0.035 &                 0.056 &      0.048469 &             0.193583 &       0.025965 &             0.016983 &         0.015 \\
31.0  &            0.0345 &                0.138 &                     0.2898 &                         0.138 &                    0.0345 &                0.0552 &      0.050085 &             0.200035 &        0.02683 &              0.01755 &        0.0155 \\
32.0  &             0.034 &                0.136 &                     0.2856 &                         0.136 &                     0.034 &                0.0544 &      0.051701 &             0.206488 &       0.027696 &             0.018116 &         0.016 \\
33.0  &            0.0335 &                0.134 &                     0.2814 &                         0.134 &                    0.0335 &                0.0536 &      0.053316 &             0.212941 &       0.028561 &             0.018682 &        0.0165 \\
34.0  &             0.033 &                0.132 &                     0.2772 &                         0.132 &                     0.033 &                0.0528 &      0.054932 &             0.219394 &       0.029426 &             0.019248 &         0.017 \\
35.0  &            0.0325 &                 0.13 &                      0.273 &                          0.13 &                    0.0325 &                 0.052 &      0.056547 &             0.225846 &       0.030292 &             0.019814 &        0.0175 \\
36.0  &             0.032 &                0.128 &                     0.2688 &                         0.128 &                     0.032 &                0.0512 &      0.058163 &             0.232299 &       0.031157 &              0.02038 &         0.018 \\
37.0  &            0.0315 &                0.126 &                     0.2646 &                         0.126 &                    0.0315 &                0.0504 &      0.059779 &             0.238752 &       0.032023 &             0.020946 &        0.0185 \\
38.0  &             0.031 &                0.124 &                     0.2604 &                         0.124 &                     0.031 &                0.0496 &      0.061394 &             0.245205 &       0.032888 &             0.021512 &         0.019 \\
39.0  &            0.0305 &                0.122 &                     0.2562 &                         0.122 &                    0.0305 &                0.0488 &       0.06301 &             0.251657 &       0.033754 &             0.022079 &        0.0195 \\
40.0  &              0.03 &                 0.12 &                      0.252 &                          0.12 &                      0.03 &                 0.048 &      0.064626 &              0.25811 &       0.034619 &             0.022645 &          0.02 \\
41.0  &            0.0295 &                0.118 &                     0.2478 &                         0.118 &                    0.0295 &                0.0472 &      0.066241 &             0.264563 &       0.035485 &             0.023211 &        0.0205 \\
42.0  &             0.029 &                0.116 &                     0.2436 &                         0.116 &                     0.029 &                0.0464 &      0.067857 &             0.271016 &        0.03635 &             0.023777 &         0.021 \\
43.0  &            0.0285 &                0.114 &                     0.2394 &                         0.114 &                    0.0285 &                0.0456 &      0.069473 &             0.277468 &       0.037216 &             0.024343 &        0.0215 \\
44.0  &             0.028 &                0.112 &                     0.2352 &                         0.112 &                     0.028 &                0.0448 &      0.071088 &             0.283921 &       0.038081 &             0.024909 &         0.022 \\
45.0  &            0.0275 &                 0.11 &                      0.231 &                          0.11 &                    0.0275 &                 0.044 &      0.072704 &             0.290374 &       0.038947 &             0.025475 &        0.0225 \\
46.0  &             0.027 &                0.108 &                     0.2268 &                         0.108 &                     0.027 &                0.0432 &       0.07432 &             0.296827 &       0.039812 &             0.026041 &         0.023 \\
47.0  &            0.0265 &                0.106 &                     0.2226 &                         0.106 &                    0.0265 &                0.0424 &      0.075935 &              0.30328 &       0.040678 &             0.026607 &        0.0235 \\
48.0  &             0.026 &                0.104 &                     0.2184 &                         0.104 &                     0.026 &                0.0416 &      0.077551 &             0.309732 &       0.041543 &             0.027174 &         0.024 \\
49.0  &            0.0255 &                0.102 &                     0.2142 &                         0.102 &                    0.0255 &                0.0408 &      0.079166 &             0.316185 &       0.042409 &              0.02774 &        0.0245 \\
50.0  &             0.025 &                  0.1 &                       0.21 &                           0.1 &                     0.025 &                  0.04 &      0.080782 &             0.322638 &       0.043274 &             0.028306 &         0.025 \\
51.0  &            0.0245 &                0.098 &                     0.2058 &                         0.098 &                    0.0245 &                0.0392 &      0.082398 &             0.329091 &        0.04414 &             0.028872 &        0.0255 \\
52.0  &             0.024 &                0.096 &                     0.2016 &                         0.096 &                     0.024 &                0.0384 &      0.084013 &             0.335543 &       0.045005 &             0.029438 &         0.026 \\
53.0  &            0.0235 &                0.094 &                     0.1974 &                         0.094 &                    0.0235 &                0.0376 &      0.085629 &             0.341996 &       0.045871 &             0.030004 &        0.0265 \\
54.0  &             0.023 &                0.092 &                     0.1932 &                         0.092 &                     0.023 &                0.0368 &      0.087245 &             0.348449 &       0.046736 &              0.03057 &         0.027 \\
55.0  &            0.0225 &                 0.09 &                      0.189 &                          0.09 &                    0.0225 &                 0.036 &       0.08886 &             0.354902 &       0.047602 &             0.031136 &        0.0275 \\
56.0  &             0.022 &                0.088 &                     0.1848 &                         0.088 &                     0.022 &                0.0352 &      0.090476 &             0.361354 &       0.048467 &             0.031703 &         0.028 \\
57.0  &            0.0215 &                0.086 &                     0.1806 &                         0.086 &                    0.0215 &                0.0344 &      0.092092 &             0.367807 &       0.049333 &             0.032269 &        0.0285 \\
58.0  &             0.021 &                0.084 &                     0.1764 &                         0.084 &                     0.021 &                0.0336 &      0.093707 &              0.37426 &       0.050198 &             0.032835 &         0.029 \\
59.0  &            0.0205 &                0.082 &                     0.1722 &                         0.082 &                    0.0205 &                0.0328 &      0.095323 &             0.380713 &       0.051064 &             0.033401 &        0.0295 \\
60.0  &              0.02 &                 0.08 &                      0.168 &                          0.08 &                      0.02 &                 0.032 &      0.096939 &             0.387165 &       0.051929 &             0.033967 &          0.03 \\
61.0  &            0.0195 &                0.078 &                     0.1638 &                         0.078 &                    0.0195 &                0.0312 &      0.098554 &             0.393618 &       0.052795 &             0.034533 &        0.0305 \\
62.0  &             0.019 &                0.076 &                     0.1596 &                         0.076 &                     0.019 &                0.0304 &       0.10017 &             0.400071 &        0.05366 &             0.035099 &         0.031 \\
63.0  &            0.0185 &                0.074 &                     0.1554 &                         0.074 &                    0.0185 &                0.0296 &      0.101785 &             0.406524 &       0.054526 &             0.035665 &        0.0315 \\
64.0  &             0.018 &                0.072 &                     0.1512 &                         0.072 &                     0.018 &                0.0288 &      0.103401 &             0.412976 &       0.055391 &             0.036231 &         0.032 \\
65.0  &            0.0175 &                 0.07 &                      0.147 &                          0.07 &                    0.0175 &                 0.028 &      0.105017 &             0.419429 &       0.056257 &             0.036798 &        0.0325 \\
66.0  &             0.017 &                0.068 &                     0.1428 &                         0.068 &                     0.017 &                0.0272 &      0.106632 &             0.425882 &       0.057122 &             0.037364 &         0.033 \\
67.0  &            0.0165 &                0.066 &                     0.1386 &                         0.066 &                    0.0165 &                0.0264 &      0.108248 &             0.432335 &       0.057988 &              0.03793 &        0.0335 \\
68.0  &             0.016 &                0.064 &                     0.1344 &                         0.064 &                     0.016 &                0.0256 &      0.109864 &             0.438787 &       0.058853 &             0.038496 &         0.034 \\
69.0  &            0.0155 &                0.062 &                     0.1302 &                         0.062 &                    0.0155 &                0.0248 &      0.111479 &              0.44524 &       0.059718 &             0.039062 &        0.0345 \\
70.0  &             0.015 &                 0.06 &                      0.126 &                          0.06 &                     0.015 &                 0.024 &      0.113095 &             0.451693 &       0.060584 &             0.039628 &         0.035 \\
71.0  &            0.0145 &                0.058 &                     0.1218 &                         0.058 &                    0.0145 &                0.0232 &      0.114711 &             0.458146 &       0.061449 &             0.040194 &        0.0355 \\
72.0  &             0.014 &                0.056 &                     0.1176 &                         0.056 &                     0.014 &                0.0224 &      0.116326 &             0.464598 &       0.062315 &              0.04076 &         0.036 \\
73.0  &            0.0135 &                0.054 &                     0.1134 &                         0.054 &                    0.0135 &                0.0216 &      0.117942 &             0.471051 &        0.06318 &             0.041327 &        0.0365 \\
74.0  &             0.013 &                0.052 &                     0.1092 &                         0.052 &                     0.013 &                0.0208 &      0.119558 &             0.477504 &       0.064046 &             0.041893 &         0.037 \\
75.0  &            0.0125 &                 0.05 &                      0.105 &                          0.05 &                    0.0125 &                  0.02 &      0.121173 &             0.483957 &       0.064911 &             0.042459 &        0.0375 \\
76.0  &             0.012 &                0.048 &                     0.1008 &                         0.048 &                     0.012 &                0.0192 &      0.122789 &             0.490409 &       0.065777 &             0.043025 &         0.038 \\
77.0  &            0.0115 &                0.046 &                     0.0966 &                         0.046 &                    0.0115 &                0.0184 &      0.124404 &             0.496862 &       0.066642 &             0.043591 &        0.0385 \\
78.0  &             0.011 &                0.044 &                     0.0924 &                         0.044 &                     0.011 &                0.0176 &       0.12602 &             0.503315 &       0.067508 &             0.044157 &         0.039 \\
79.0  &            0.0105 &                0.042 &                     0.0882 &                         0.042 &                    0.0105 &                0.0168 &      0.127636 &             0.509768 &       0.068373 &             0.044723 &        0.0395 \\
80.0  &              0.01 &                 0.04 &                      0.084 &                          0.04 &                      0.01 &                 0.016 &      0.129251 &              0.51622 &       0.069239 &             0.045289 &          0.04 \\
81.0  &            0.0095 &                0.038 &                     0.0798 &                         0.038 &                    0.0095 &                0.0152 &      0.130867 &             0.522673 &       0.070104 &             0.045855 &        0.0405 \\
82.0  &             0.009 &                0.036 &                     0.0756 &                         0.036 &                     0.009 &                0.0144 &      0.132483 &             0.529126 &        0.07097 &             0.046422 &         0.041 \\
83.0  &            0.0085 &                0.034 &                     0.0714 &                         0.034 &                    0.0085 &                0.0136 &      0.134098 &             0.535579 &       0.071835 &             0.046988 &        0.0415 \\
84.0  &             0.008 &                0.032 &                     0.0672 &                         0.032 &                     0.008 &                0.0128 &      0.135714 &             0.542031 &       0.072701 &             0.047554 &         0.042 \\
85.0  &            0.0075 &                 0.03 &                      0.063 &                          0.03 &                    0.0075 &                 0.012 &       0.13733 &             0.548484 &       0.073566 &              0.04812 &        0.0425 \\
86.0  &             0.007 &                0.028 &                     0.0588 &                         0.028 &                     0.007 &                0.0112 &      0.138945 &             0.554937 &       0.074432 &             0.048686 &         0.043 \\
87.0  &            0.0065 &                0.026 &                     0.0546 &                         0.026 &                    0.0065 &                0.0104 &      0.140561 &              0.56139 &       0.075297 &             0.049252 &        0.0435 \\
88.0  &             0.006 &                0.024 &                     0.0504 &                         0.024 &                     0.006 &                0.0096 &      0.142177 &             0.567842 &       0.076163 &             0.049818 &         0.044 \\
89.0  &            0.0055 &                0.022 &                     0.0462 &                         0.022 &                    0.0055 &                0.0088 &      0.143792 &             0.574295 &       0.077028 &             0.050384 &        0.0445 \\
90.0  &             0.005 &                 0.02 &                      0.042 &                          0.02 &                     0.005 &                 0.008 &      0.145408 &             0.580748 &       0.077894 &              0.05095 &         0.045 \\
91.0  &            0.0045 &                0.018 &                     0.0378 &                         0.018 &                    0.0045 &                0.0072 &      0.147023 &             0.587201 &       0.078759 &             0.051517 &        0.0455 \\
92.0  &             0.004 &                0.016 &                     0.0336 &                         0.016 &                     0.004 &                0.0064 &      0.148639 &             0.593653 &       0.079625 &             0.052083 &         0.046 \\
93.0  &            0.0035 &                0.014 &                     0.0294 &                         0.014 &                    0.0035 &                0.0056 &      0.150255 &             0.600106 &        0.08049 &             0.052649 &        0.0465 \\
94.0  &             0.003 &                0.012 &                     0.0252 &                         0.012 &                     0.003 &                0.0048 &       0.15187 &             0.606559 &       0.081356 &             0.053215 &         0.047 \\
95.0  &            0.0025 &                 0.01 &                      0.021 &                          0.01 &                    0.0025 &                 0.004 &      0.153486 &             0.613012 &       0.082221 &             0.053781 &        0.0475 \\
96.0  &             0.002 &                0.008 &                     0.0168 &                         0.008 &                     0.002 &                0.0032 &      0.155102 &             0.619465 &       0.083087 &             0.054347 &         0.048 \\
97.0  &            0.0015 &                0.006 &                     0.0126 &                         0.006 &                    0.0015 &                0.0024 &      0.156717 &             0.625917 &       0.083952 &             0.054913 &        0.0485 \\
98.0  &             0.001 &                0.004 &                     0.0084 &                         0.004 &                     0.001 &                0.0016 &      0.158333 &              0.63237 &       0.084818 &             0.055479 &         0.049 \\
99.0  &            0.0005 &                0.002 &                     0.0042 &                         0.002 &                    0.0005 &                0.0008 &      0.159949 &             0.638823 &       0.085683 &             0.056046 &        0.0495 \\
100.0 &               0.0 &                  0.0 &                        0.0 &                           0.0 &                       0.0 &                   0.0 &      0.161564 &             0.645276 &       0.086549 &             0.056612 &          0.05 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Look up the `longtable` package. `tabular` does not support page breaks.

Comment: With 10 columns you may need both landscape and longtable.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414935/make-longtable-in-landscape-mode-wider-than-textwidth for example.

Comment: @mico I don't understand why you closed the question as a duplicate. The answers you indicate only deal with tables consisting of numeric entries only. They do not deal with this table which has text column headings which can be configured to take up less width.

Comment: I agree with @PeterWilson, this questions needs some effort at how tables go horizontally. Adding `\usepackage{pdflscape}` and using `\begin{landscape}{\small\begin{longtable{lp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}} ...` is a starting point, despite ugly results.

Comment: I'd suggest the `tabularray` with extra libraries, s.a. `booktabs` and `sunitx`. See an example solution on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/cphpsrnzqpmn) (the code would be too long to share here)

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution to the too wide table problem is to use `p{length}`, not optimal, not elegant, but sufficient to fit win a landscape page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{\small
  \begin{longtable}{lp{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
    \toprule
    {}    & Money Market Euro & Bond Euro Short Term & Bond Euro Medium-Long Term & Global Bond Developed Markets & Corporate Bond High Yield & Emerging Markets Bond & Equity Europe & Equity North America & Equity Pacific & Equity Emerg Markets & Opportunities \\
    \midrule
<ALL YOUR DATA>
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

This is the very ugly preliminar result

[image]

Some effort still needs to be applied to better fit text and numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, the table won't fit any standard page. At 10 point size, the headers have a width of more than 1200pt, which is about 43.5 centimeters.

You can use acronyms that are explained in the table foot. Reducing the intercolumn spaces and the font size will do the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\tabcolsep}
\footnotesize
\newcommand{\tablefoot}{%
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize
  MMM = Money Market Euro;
  BEST = Bond Euro Short Term;
  BEMLT = Bond Euro Medium-Long Term;} \\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize
  GBDM = Global Bond Developed Markets;
  CBHY = Corporate Bond High Yield;} \\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize
  EMB = Emerging Markets Bond;
  EE = Equity Europe;
  ENA = Equity North America;} \\
\multicolumn{12}{@{}l@{}}{\scriptsize
  EP = Equity Pacific;
  EEM = Equity Emergent Markets;
  O = Opportunities} \\}

\begin{longtable}{@{}llllllllllll@{}}

\toprule
{} & {MMM} & {BEST} & {BEMLT} & {GBDM} & {CBHY} & {EMB} & {EE} & {ENA} & {EP} & {EEM} & {O} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\tablefoot
\endfoot

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\tablefoot
\endlastfoot

\midrule
0.0   &              0.05 &                  0.2 &                       0.42 &                           0.2 &                      0.05 &                  0.08 &           0.0 &                  0.0 &            0.0 &                  0.0 &           0.0 \\
1.0   &            0.0495 &                0.198 &                     0.4158 &                         0.198 &                    0.0495 &                0.0792 &      0.001616 &             0.006453 &       0.000865 &             0.000566 &        0.0005 \\
2.0   &             0.049 &                0.196 &                     0.4116 &                         0.196 &                     0.049 &                0.0784 &      0.003231 &             0.012906 &       0.001731 &             0.001132 &         0.001 \\
3.0   &            0.0485 &                0.194 &                     0.4074 &                         0.194 &                    0.0485 &                0.0776 &      0.004847 &             0.019358 &       0.002596 &             0.001698 &        0.0015 \\
4.0   &             0.048 &                0.192 &                     0.4032 &                         0.192 &                     0.048 &                0.0768 &      0.006463 &             0.025811 &       0.003462 &             0.002264 &         0.002 \\
5.0   &            0.0475 &                 0.19 &                      0.399 &                          0.19 &                    0.0475 &                 0.076 &      0.008078 &             0.032264 &       0.004327 &             0.002831 &        0.0025 \\
6.0   &             0.047 &                0.188 &                     0.3948 &                         0.188 &                     0.047 &                0.0752 &      0.009694 &             0.038717 &       0.005193 &             0.003397 &         0.003 \\
7.0   &            0.0465 &                0.186 &                     0.3906 &                         0.186 &                    0.0465 &                0.0744 &      0.011309 &             0.045169 &       0.006058 &             0.003963 &        0.0035 \\
8.0   &             0.046 &                0.184 &                     0.3864 &                         0.184 &                     0.046 &                0.0736 &      0.012925 &             0.051622 &       0.006924 &             0.004529 &         0.004 \\
9.0   &            0.0455 &                0.182 &                     0.3822 &                         0.182 &                    0.0455 &                0.0728 &      0.014541 &             0.058075 &       0.007789 &             0.005095 &        0.0045 \\
10.0  &             0.045 &                 0.18 &                      0.378 &                          0.18 &                     0.045 &                 0.072 &      0.016156 &             0.064528 &       0.008655 &             0.005661 &         0.005 \\
11.0  &            0.0445 &                0.178 &                     0.3738 &                         0.178 &                    0.0445 &                0.0712 &      0.017772 &              0.07098 &        0.00952 &             0.006227 &        0.0055 \\
12.0  &             0.044 &                0.176 &                     0.3696 &                         0.176 &                     0.044 &                0.0704 &      0.019388 &             0.077433 &       0.010386 &             0.006793 &         0.006 \\
13.0  &            0.0435 &                0.174 &                     0.3654 &                         0.174 &                    0.0435 &                0.0696 &      0.021003 &             0.083886 &       0.011251 &              0.00736 &        0.0065 \\
14.0  &             0.043 &                0.172 &                     0.3612 &                         0.172 &                     0.043 &                0.0688 &      0.022619 &             0.090339 &       0.012117 &             0.007926 &         0.007 \\
15.0  &            0.0425 &                 0.17 &                      0.357 &                          0.17 &                    0.0425 &                 0.068 &      0.024235 &             0.096791 &       0.012982 &             0.008492 &        0.0075 \\
16.0  &             0.042 &                0.168 &                     0.3528 &                         0.168 &                     0.042 &                0.0672 &       0.02585 &             0.103244 &       0.013848 &             0.009058 &         0.008 \\
17.0  &            0.0415 &                0.166 &                     0.3486 &                         0.166 &                    0.0415 &                0.0664 &      0.027466 &             0.109697 &       0.014713 &             0.009624 &        0.0085 \\
18.0  &             0.041 &                0.164 &                     0.3444 &                         0.164 &                     0.041 &                0.0656 &      0.029082 &              0.11615 &       0.015579 &              0.01019 &         0.009 \\
19.0  &            0.0405 &                0.162 &                     0.3402 &                         0.162 &                    0.0405 &                0.0648 &      0.030697 &             0.122602 &       0.016444 &             0.010756 &        0.0095 \\
20.0  &              0.04 &                 0.16 &                      0.336 &                          0.16 &                      0.04 &                 0.064 &      0.032313 &             0.129055 &        0.01731 &             0.011322 &          0.01 \\
21.0  &            0.0395 &                0.158 &                     0.3318 &                         0.158 &                    0.0395 &                0.0632 &      0.033928 &             0.135508 &       0.018175 &             0.011888 &        0.0105 \\
22.0  &             0.039 &                0.156 &                     0.3276 &                         0.156 &                     0.039 &                0.0624 &      0.035544 &             0.141961 &       0.019041 &             0.012455 &         0.011 \\
23.0  &            0.0385 &                0.154 &                     0.3234 &                         0.154 &                    0.0385 &                0.0616 &       0.03716 &             0.148413 &       0.019906 &             0.013021 &        0.0115 \\
24.0  &             0.038 &                0.152 &                     0.3192 &                         0.152 &                     0.038 &                0.0608 &      0.038775 &             0.154866 &       0.020772 &             0.013587 &         0.012 \\
25.0  &            0.0375 &                 0.15 &                      0.315 &                          0.15 &                    0.0375 &                  0.06 &      0.040391 &             0.161319 &       0.021637 &             0.014153 &        0.0125 \\
26.0  &             0.037 &                0.148 &                     0.3108 &                         0.148 &                     0.037 &                0.0592 &      0.042007 &             0.167772 &       0.022503 &             0.014719 &         0.013 \\
27.0  &            0.0365 &                0.146 &                     0.3066 &                         0.146 &                    0.0365 &                0.0584 &      0.043622 &             0.174224 &       0.023368 &             0.015285 &        0.0135 \\
28.0  &             0.036 &                0.144 &                     0.3024 &                         0.144 &                     0.036 &                0.0576 &      0.045238 &             0.180677 &       0.024234 &             0.015851 &         0.014 \\
29.0  &            0.0355 &                0.142 &                     0.2982 &                         0.142 &                    0.0355 &                0.0568 &      0.046854 &              0.18713 &       0.025099 &             0.016417 &        0.0145 \\
30.0  &             0.035 &                 0.14 &                      0.294 &                          0.14 &                     0.035 &                 0.056 &      0.048469 &             0.193583 &       0.025965 &             0.016983 &         0.015 \\
31.0  &            0.0345 &                0.138 &                     0.2898 &                         0.138 &                    0.0345 &                0.0552 &      0.050085 &             0.200035 &        0.02683 &              0.01755 &        0.0155 \\
32.0  &             0.034 &                0.136 &                     0.2856 &                         0.136 &                     0.034 &                0.0544 &      0.051701 &             0.206488 &       0.027696 &             0.018116 &         0.016 \\
33.0  &            0.0335 &                0.134 &                     0.2814 &                         0.134 &                    0.0335 &                0.0536 &      0.053316 &             0.212941 &       0.028561 &             0.018682 &        0.0165 \\
34.0  &             0.033 &                0.132 &                     0.2772 &                         0.132 &                     0.033 &                0.0528 &      0.054932 &             0.219394 &       0.029426 &             0.019248 &         0.017 \\
35.0  &            0.0325 &                 0.13 &                      0.273 &                          0.13 &                    0.0325 &                 0.052 &      0.056547 &             0.225846 &       0.030292 &             0.019814 &        0.0175 \\
36.0  &             0.032 &                0.128 &                     0.2688 &                         0.128 &                     0.032 &                0.0512 &      0.058163 &             0.232299 &       0.031157 &              0.02038 &         0.018 \\
37.0  &            0.0315 &                0.126 &                     0.2646 &                         0.126 &                    0.0315 &                0.0504 &      0.059779 &             0.238752 &       0.032023 &             0.020946 &        0.0185 \\
38.0  &             0.031 &                0.124 &                     0.2604 &                         0.124 &                     0.031 &                0.0496 &      0.061394 &             0.245205 &       0.032888 &             0.021512 &         0.019 \\
39.0  &            0.0305 &                0.122 &                     0.2562 &                         0.122 &                    0.0305 &                0.0488 &       0.06301 &             0.251657 &       0.033754 &             0.022079 &        0.0195 \\
40.0  &              0.03 &                 0.12 &                      0.252 &                          0.12 &                      0.03 &                 0.048 &      0.064626 &              0.25811 &       0.034619 &             0.022645 &          0.02 \\
41.0  &            0.0295 &                0.118 &                     0.2478 &                         0.118 &                    0.0295 &                0.0472 &      0.066241 &             0.264563 &       0.035485 &             0.023211 &        0.0205 \\
42.0  &             0.029 &                0.116 &                     0.2436 &                         0.116 &                     0.029 &                0.0464 &      0.067857 &             0.271016 &        0.03635 &             0.023777 &         0.021 \\
43.0  &            0.0285 &                0.114 &                     0.2394 &                         0.114 &                    0.0285 &                0.0456 &      0.069473 &             0.277468 &       0.037216 &             0.024343 &        0.0215 \\
44.0  &             0.028 &                0.112 &                     0.2352 &                         0.112 &                     0.028 &                0.0448 &      0.071088 &             0.283921 &       0.038081 &             0.024909 &         0.022 \\
45.0  &            0.0275 &                 0.11 &                      0.231 &                          0.11 &                    0.0275 &                 0.044 &      0.072704 &             0.290374 &       0.038947 &             0.025475 &        0.0225 \\
46.0  &             0.027 &                0.108 &                     0.2268 &                         0.108 &                     0.027 &                0.0432 &       0.07432 &             0.296827 &       0.039812 &             0.026041 &         0.023 \\
47.0  &            0.0265 &                0.106 &                     0.2226 &                         0.106 &                    0.0265 &                0.0424 &      0.075935 &              0.30328 &       0.040678 &             0.026607 &        0.0235 \\
48.0  &             0.026 &                0.104 &                     0.2184 &                         0.104 &                     0.026 &                0.0416 &      0.077551 &             0.309732 &       0.041543 &             0.027174 &         0.024 \\
49.0  &            0.0255 &                0.102 &                     0.2142 &                         0.102 &                    0.0255 &                0.0408 &      0.079166 &             0.316185 &       0.042409 &              0.02774 &        0.0245 \\
50.0  &             0.025 &                  0.1 &                       0.21 &                           0.1 &                     0.025 &                  0.04 &      0.080782 &             0.322638 &       0.043274 &             0.028306 &         0.025 \\
51.0  &            0.0245 &                0.098 &                     0.2058 &                         0.098 &                    0.0245 &                0.0392 &      0.082398 &             0.329091 &        0.04414 &             0.028872 &        0.0255 \\
52.0  &             0.024 &                0.096 &                     0.2016 &                         0.096 &                     0.024 &                0.0384 &      0.084013 &             0.335543 &       0.045005 &             0.029438 &         0.026 \\
53.0  &            0.0235 &                0.094 &                     0.1974 &                         0.094 &                    0.0235 &                0.0376 &      0.085629 &             0.341996 &       0.045871 &             0.030004 &        0.0265 \\
54.0  &             0.023 &                0.092 &                     0.1932 &                         0.092 &                     0.023 &                0.0368 &      0.087245 &             0.348449 &       0.046736 &              0.03057 &         0.027 \\
55.0  &            0.0225 &                 0.09 &                      0.189 &                          0.09 &                    0.0225 &                 0.036 &       0.08886 &             0.354902 &       0.047602 &             0.031136 &        0.0275 \\
56.0  &             0.022 &                0.088 &                     0.1848 &                         0.088 &                     0.022 &                0.0352 &      0.090476 &             0.361354 &       0.048467 &             0.031703 &         0.028 \\
57.0  &            0.0215 &                0.086 &                     0.1806 &                         0.086 &                    0.0215 &                0.0344 &      0.092092 &             0.367807 &       0.049333 &             0.032269 &        0.0285 \\
58.0  &             0.021 &                0.084 &                     0.1764 &                         0.084 &                     0.021 &                0.0336 &      0.093707 &              0.37426 &       0.050198 &             0.032835 &         0.029 \\
59.0  &            0.0205 &                0.082 &                     0.1722 &                         0.082 &                    0.0205 &                0.0328 &      0.095323 &             0.380713 &       0.051064 &             0.033401 &        0.0295 \\
60.0  &              0.02 &                 0.08 &                      0.168 &                          0.08 &                      0.02 &                 0.032 &      0.096939 &             0.387165 &       0.051929 &             0.033967 &          0.03 \\
61.0  &            0.0195 &                0.078 &                     0.1638 &                         0.078 &                    0.0195 &                0.0312 &      0.098554 &             0.393618 &       0.052795 &             0.034533 &        0.0305 \\
62.0  &             0.019 &                0.076 &                     0.1596 &                         0.076 &                     0.019 &                0.0304 &       0.10017 &             0.400071 &        0.05366 &             0.035099 &         0.031 \\
63.0  &            0.0185 &                0.074 &                     0.1554 &                         0.074 &                    0.0185 &                0.0296 &      0.101785 &             0.406524 &       0.054526 &             0.035665 &        0.0315 \\
64.0  &             0.018 &                0.072 &                     0.1512 &                         0.072 &                     0.018 &                0.0288 &      0.103401 &             0.412976 &       0.055391 &             0.036231 &         0.032 \\
65.0  &            0.0175 &                 0.07 &                      0.147 &                          0.07 &                    0.0175 &                 0.028 &      0.105017 &             0.419429 &       0.056257 &             0.036798 &        0.0325 \\
66.0  &             0.017 &                0.068 &                     0.1428 &                         0.068 &                     0.017 &                0.0272 &      0.106632 &             0.425882 &       0.057122 &             0.037364 &         0.033 \\
67.0  &            0.0165 &                0.066 &                     0.1386 &                         0.066 &                    0.0165 &                0.0264 &      0.108248 &             0.432335 &       0.057988 &              0.03793 &        0.0335 \\
68.0  &             0.016 &                0.064 &                     0.1344 &                         0.064 &                     0.016 &                0.0256 &      0.109864 &             0.438787 &       0.058853 &             0.038496 &         0.034 \\
69.0  &            0.0155 &                0.062 &                     0.1302 &                         0.062 &                    0.0155 &                0.0248 &      0.111479 &              0.44524 &       0.059718 &             0.039062 &        0.0345 \\
70.0  &             0.015 &                 0.06 &                      0.126 &                          0.06 &                     0.015 &                 0.024 &      0.113095 &             0.451693 &       0.060584 &             0.039628 &         0.035 \\
71.0  &            0.0145 &                0.058 &                     0.1218 &                         0.058 &                    0.0145 &                0.0232 &      0.114711 &             0.458146 &       0.061449 &             0.040194 &        0.0355 \\
72.0  &             0.014 &                0.056 &                     0.1176 &                         0.056 &                     0.014 &                0.0224 &      0.116326 &             0.464598 &       0.062315 &              0.04076 &         0.036 \\
73.0  &            0.0135 &                0.054 &                     0.1134 &                         0.054 &                    0.0135 &                0.0216 &      0.117942 &             0.471051 &        0.06318 &             0.041327 &        0.0365 \\
74.0  &             0.013 &                0.052 &                     0.1092 &                         0.052 &                     0.013 &                0.0208 &      0.119558 &             0.477504 &       0.064046 &             0.041893 &         0.037 \\
75.0  &            0.0125 &                 0.05 &                      0.105 &                          0.05 &                    0.0125 &                  0.02 &      0.121173 &             0.483957 &       0.064911 &             0.042459 &        0.0375 \\
76.0  &             0.012 &                0.048 &                     0.1008 &                         0.048 &                     0.012 &                0.0192 &      0.122789 &             0.490409 &       0.065777 &             0.043025 &         0.038 \\
77.0  &            0.0115 &                0.046 &                     0.0966 &                         0.046 &                    0.0115 &                0.0184 &      0.124404 &             0.496862 &       0.066642 &             0.043591 &        0.0385 \\
78.0  &             0.011 &                0.044 &                     0.0924 &                         0.044 &                     0.011 &                0.0176 &       0.12602 &             0.503315 &       0.067508 &             0.044157 &         0.039 \\
79.0  &            0.0105 &                0.042 &                     0.0882 &                         0.042 &                    0.0105 &                0.0168 &      0.127636 &             0.509768 &       0.068373 &             0.044723 &        0.0395 \\
80.0  &              0.01 &                 0.04 &                      0.084 &                          0.04 &                      0.01 &                 0.016 &      0.129251 &              0.51622 &       0.069239 &             0.045289 &          0.04 \\
81.0  &            0.0095 &                0.038 &                     0.0798 &                         0.038 &                    0.0095 &                0.0152 &      0.130867 &             0.522673 &       0.070104 &             0.045855 &        0.0405 \\
82.0  &             0.009 &                0.036 &                     0.0756 &                         0.036 &                     0.009 &                0.0144 &      0.132483 &             0.529126 &        0.07097 &             0.046422 &         0.041 \\
83.0  &            0.0085 &                0.034 &                     0.0714 &                         0.034 &                    0.0085 &                0.0136 &      0.134098 &             0.535579 &       0.071835 &             0.046988 &        0.0415 \\
84.0  &             0.008 &                0.032 &                     0.0672 &                         0.032 &                     0.008 &                0.0128 &      0.135714 &             0.542031 &       0.072701 &             0.047554 &         0.042 \\
85.0  &            0.0075 &                 0.03 &                      0.063 &                          0.03 &                    0.0075 &                 0.012 &       0.13733 &             0.548484 &       0.073566 &              0.04812 &        0.0425 \\
86.0  &             0.007 &                0.028 &                     0.0588 &                         0.028 &                     0.007 &                0.0112 &      0.138945 &             0.554937 &       0.074432 &             0.048686 &         0.043 \\
87.0  &            0.0065 &                0.026 &                     0.0546 &                         0.026 &                    0.0065 &                0.0104 &      0.140561 &              0.56139 &       0.075297 &             0.049252 &        0.0435 \\
88.0  &             0.006 &                0.024 &                     0.0504 &                         0.024 &                     0.006 &                0.0096 &      0.142177 &             0.567842 &       0.076163 &             0.049818 &         0.044 \\
89.0  &            0.0055 &                0.022 &                     0.0462 &                         0.022 &                    0.0055 &                0.0088 &      0.143792 &             0.574295 &       0.077028 &             0.050384 &        0.0445 \\
90.0  &             0.005 &                 0.02 &                      0.042 &                          0.02 &                     0.005 &                 0.008 &      0.145408 &             0.580748 &       0.077894 &              0.05095 &         0.045 \\
91.0  &            0.0045 &                0.018 &                     0.0378 &                         0.018 &                    0.0045 &                0.0072 &      0.147023 &             0.587201 &       0.078759 &             0.051517 &        0.0455 \\
92.0  &             0.004 &                0.016 &                     0.0336 &                         0.016 &                     0.004 &                0.0064 &      0.148639 &             0.593653 &       0.079625 &             0.052083 &         0.046 \\
93.0  &            0.0035 &                0.014 &                     0.0294 &                         0.014 &                    0.0035 &                0.0056 &      0.150255 &             0.600106 &        0.08049 &             0.052649 &        0.0465 \\
94.0  &             0.003 &                0.012 &                     0.0252 &                         0.012 &                     0.003 &                0.0048 &       0.15187 &             0.606559 &       0.081356 &             0.053215 &         0.047 \\
95.0  &            0.0025 &                 0.01 &                      0.021 &                          0.01 &                    0.0025 &                 0.004 &      0.153486 &             0.613012 &       0.082221 &             0.053781 &        0.0475 \\
96.0  &             0.002 &                0.008 &                     0.0168 &                         0.008 &                     0.002 &                0.0032 &      0.155102 &             0.619465 &       0.083087 &             0.054347 &         0.048 \\
97.0  &            0.0015 &                0.006 &                     0.0126 &                         0.006 &                    0.0015 &                0.0024 &      0.156717 &             0.625917 &       0.083952 &             0.054913 &        0.0485 \\
98.0  &             0.001 &                0.004 &                     0.0084 &                         0.004 &                     0.001 &                0.0016 &      0.158333 &              0.63237 &       0.084818 &             0.055479 &         0.049 \\
99.0  &            0.0005 &                0.002 &                     0.0042 &                         0.002 &                    0.0005 &                0.0008 &      0.159949 &             0.638823 &       0.085683 &             0.056046 &        0.0495 \\
100.0 &               0.0 &                  0.0 &                        0.0 &                           0.0 &                       0.0 &                   0.0 &      0.161564 &             0.645276 &       0.086549 &             0.056612 &          0.05 \\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a \tikz\node to force the text width.
We can use the other \node properties to adjust the alignment.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}


\newcommand{\tNode}[1]{
\tikz\node[text width=2.em]{#1};
}

{\small
\begin{longtable}{llllllllllll} \hline
{} & \tNode{Money Market Euro} & \tNode{Bond Euro Short Term} & \tNode{Bond Euro Medium-Long Term} & \tNode{Global Bond Developed Markets} & \tNode{Corporate Bond High Yield } & 
\tNode{Emerging Markets Bond} & \tNode{Equity Europe} & \tNode{Equity North America} & \tNode{Equity Pacific}
 &\tNode{ Equity Emerg Markets }& \tNode{Opportunities }  \\ \hline
0.0   &              0.05 &                  0.2 &                       0.42 &                           0.2 &                      0.05 &                  0.08 &           0.0 &                  0.0 &            0.0 &                  0.0 &           0.0 \\
1.0   &            0.0495 &                0.198 &                     0.4158 &                         0.198 &                    0.0495 &                0.0792 &      0.001616 &             0.006453 &       0.000865 &             0.000566 &        0.0005 \\
2.0   &             0.049 &                0.196 &                     0.4116 &                         0.196 &                     0.049 &                0.0784 &      0.003231 &             0.012906 &       0.001731 &             0.001132 &         0.001 \\
3.0   &            0.0485 &                0.194 &                     0.4074 &                         0.194 &                    0.0485 &                0.0776 &      0.004847 &             0.019358 &       0.002596 &             0.001698 &        0.0015 \\
4.0   &             0.048 &                0.192 &                     0.4032 &                         0.192 &                     0.048 &                0.0768 &      0.006463 &             0.025811 &       0.003462 &             0.002264 &         0.002 \\
5.0   &            0.0475 &                 0.19 &                      0.399 &                          0.19 &                    0.0475 &                 0.076 &      0.008078 &             0.032264 &       0.004327 &             0.002831 &        0.0025 \\
6.0   &             0.047 &                0.188 &                     0.3948 &                         0.188 &                     0.047 &                0.0752 &      0.009694 &             0.038717 &       0.005193 &             0.003397 &         0.003 \\
7.0   &            0.0465 &                0.186 &                     0.3906 &                         0.186 &                    0.0465 &                0.0744 &      0.011309 &             0.045169 &       0.006058 &             0.003963 &        0.0035 \\
8.0   &             0.046 &                0.184 &                     0.3864 &                         0.184 &                     0.046 &                0.0736 &      0.012925 &             0.051622 &       0.006924 &             0.004529 &         0.004 \\
9.0   &            0.0455 &                0.182 &                     0.3822 &                         0.182 &                    0.0455 &                0.0728 &      0.014541 &             0.058075 &       0.007789 &             0.005095 &        0.0045 \\
10.0  &             0.045 &                 0.18 &                      0.378 &                          0.18 &                     0.045 &                 0.072 &      0.016156 &             0.064528 &       0.008655 &             0.005661 &         0.005 \\
11.0  &            0.0445 &                0.178 &                     0.3738 &                         0.178 &                    0.0445 &                0.0712 &      0.017772 &              0.07098 &        0.00952 &             0.006227 &        0.0055 \\
12.0  &             0.044 &                0.176 &                     0.3696 &                         0.176 &                     0.044 &                0.0704 &      0.019388 &             0.077433 &       0.010386 &             0.006793 &         0.006 \\
13.0  &            0.0435 &                0.174 &                     0.3654 &                         0.174 &                    0.0435 &                0.0696 &      0.021003 &             0.083886 &       0.011251 &              0.00736 &        0.0065 \\
14.0  &             0.043 &                0.172 &                     0.3612 &                         0.172 &                     0.043 &                0.0688 &      0.022619 &             0.090339 &       0.012117 &             0.007926 &         0.007 \\
15.0  &            0.0425 &                 0.17 &                      0.357 &                          0.17 &                    0.0425 &                 0.068 &      0.024235 &             0.096791 &       0.012982 &             0.008492 &        0.0075 \\
16.0  &             0.042 &                0.168 &                     0.3528 &                         0.168 &                     0.042 &                0.0672 &       0.02585 &             0.103244 &       0.013848 &             0.009058 &         0.008 \\
17.0  &            0.0415 &                0.166 &                     0.3486 &                         0.166 &                    0.0415 &                0.0664 &      0.027466 &             0.109697 &       0.014713 &             0.009624 &        0.0085 \\
18.0  &             0.041 &                0.164 &                     0.3444 &                         0.164 &                     0.041 &                0.0656 &      0.029082 &              0.11615 &       0.015579 &              0.01019 &         0.009 \\
19.0  &            0.0405 &                0.162 &                     0.3402 &                         0.162 &                    0.0405 &                0.0648 &      0.030697 &             0.122602 &       0.016444 &             0.010756 &        0.0095 \\
20.0  &              0.04 &                 0.16 &                      0.336 &                          0.16 &                      0.04 &                 0.064 &      0.032313 &             0.129055 &        0.01731 &             0.011322 &          0.01 \\
21.0  &            0.0395 &                0.158 &                     0.3318 &                         0.158 &                    0.0395 &                0.0632 &      0.033928 &             0.135508 &       0.018175 &             0.011888 &        0.0105 \\
22.0  &             0.039 &                0.156 &                     0.3276 &                         0.156 &                     0.039 &                0.0624 &      0.035544 &             0.141961 &       0.019041 &             0.012455 &         0.011 \\
23.0  &            0.0385 &                0.154 &                     0.3234 &                         0.154 &                    0.0385 &                0.0616 &       0.03716 &             0.148413 &       0.019906 &             0.013021 &        0.0115 \\
24.0  &             0.038 &                0.152 &                     0.3192 &                         0.152 &                     0.038 &                0.0608 &      0.038775 &             0.154866 &       0.020772 &             0.013587 &         0.012 \\
25.0  &            0.0375 &                 0.15 &                      0.315 &                          0.15 &                    0.0375 &                  0.06 &      0.040391 &             0.161319 &       0.021637 &             0.014153 &        0.0125 \\
26.0  &             0.037 &                0.148 &                     0.3108 &                         0.148 &                     0.037 &                0.0592 &      0.042007 &             0.167772 &       0.022503 &             0.014719 &         0.013 \\
27.0  &            0.0365 &                0.146 &                     0.3066 &                         0.146 &                    0.0365 &                0.0584 &      0.043622 &             0.174224 &       0.023368 &             0.015285 &        0.0135 \\
28.0  &             0.036 &                0.144 &                     0.3024 &                         0.144 &                     0.036 &                0.0576 &      0.045238 &             0.180677 &       0.024234 &             0.015851 &         0.014 \\
29.0  &            0.0355 &                0.142 &                     0.2982 &                         0.142 &                    0.0355 &                0.0568 &      0.046854 &              0.18713 &       0.025099 &             0.016417 &        0.0145 \\
30.0  &             0.035 &                 0.14 &                      0.294 &                          0.14 &                     0.035 &                 0.056 &      0.048469 &             0.193583 &       0.025965 &             0.016983 &         0.015 \\
31.0  &            0.0345 &                0.138 &                     0.2898 &                         0.138 &                    0.0345 &                0.0552 &      0.050085 &             0.200035 &        0.02683 &              0.01755 &        0.0155 \\
32.0  &             0.034 &                0.136 &                     0.2856 &                         0.136 &                     0.034 &                0.0544 &      0.051701 &             0.206488 &       0.027696 &             0.018116 &         0.016 \\
33.0  &            0.0335 &                0.134 &                     0.2814 &                         0.134 &                    0.0335 &                0.0536 &      0.053316 &             0.212941 &       0.028561 &             0.018682 &        0.0165 \\
34.0  &             0.033 &                0.132 &                     0.2772 &                         0.132 &                     0.033 &                0.0528 &      0.054932 &             0.219394 &       0.029426 &             0.019248 &         0.017 \\
35.0  &            0.0325 &                 0.13 &                      0.273 &                          0.13 &                    0.0325 &                 0.052 &      0.056547 &             0.225846 &       0.030292 &             0.019814 &        0.0175 \\
36.0  &             0.032 &                0.128 &                     0.2688 &                         0.128 &                     0.032 &                0.0512 &      0.058163 &             0.232299 &       0.031157 &              0.02038 &         0.018 \\
37.0  &            0.0315 &                0.126 &                     0.2646 &                         0.126 &                    0.0315 &                0.0504 &      0.059779 &             0.238752 &       0.032023 &             0.020946 &        0.0185 \\
38.0  &             0.031 &                0.124 &                     0.2604 &                         0.124 &                     0.031 &                0.0496 &      0.061394 &             0.245205 &       0.032888 &             0.021512 &         0.019 \\
39.0  &            0.0305 &                0.122 &                     0.2562 &                         0.122 &                    0.0305 &                0.0488 &       0.06301 &             0.251657 &       0.033754 &             0.022079 &        0.0195 \\
40.0  &              0.03 &                 0.12 &                      0.252 &                          0.12 &                      0.03 &                 0.048 &      0.064626 &              0.25811 &       0.034619 &             0.022645 &          0.02 \\
41.0  &            0.0295 &                0.118 &                     0.2478 &                         0.118 &                    0.0295 &                0.0472 &      0.066241 &             0.264563 &       0.035485 &             0.023211 &        0.0205 \\
42.0  &             0.029 &                0.116 &                     0.2436 &                         0.116 &                     0.029 &                0.0464 &      0.067857 &             0.271016 &        0.03635 &             0.023777 &         0.021 \\
43.0  &            0.0285 &                0.114 &                     0.2394 &                         0.114 &                    0.0285 &                0.0456 &      0.069473 &             0.277468 &       0.037216 &             0.024343 &        0.0215 \\
44.0  &             0.028 &                0.112 &                     0.2352 &                         0.112 &                     0.028 &                0.0448 &      0.071088 &             0.283921 &       0.038081 &             0.024909 &         0.022 \\
45.0  &            0.0275 &                 0.11 &                      0.231 &                          0.11 &                    0.0275 &                 0.044 &      0.072704 &             0.290374 &       0.038947 &             0.025475 &        0.0225 \\
46.0  &             0.027 &                0.108 &                     0.2268 &                         0.108 &                     0.027 &                0.0432 &       0.07432 &             0.296827 &       0.039812 &             0.026041 &         0.023 \\
47.0  &            0.0265 &                0.106 &                     0.2226 &                         0.106 &                    0.0265 &                0.0424 &      0.075935 &              0.30328 &       0.040678 &             0.026607 &        0.0235 \\
48.0  &             0.026 &                0.104 &                     0.2184 &                         0.104 &                     0.026 &                0.0416 &      0.077551 &             0.309732 &       0.041543 &             0.027174 &         0.024 \\
49.0  &            0.0255 &                0.102 &                     0.2142 &                         0.102 &                    0.0255 &                0.0408 &      0.079166 &             0.316185 &       0.042409 &              0.02774 &        0.0245 \\
50.0  &             0.025 &                  0.1 &                       0.21 &                           0.1 &                     0.025 &                  0.04 &      0.080782 &             0.322638 &       0.043274 &             0.028306 &         0.025 \\
51.0  &            0.0245 &                0.098 &                     0.2058 &                         0.098 &                    0.0245 &                0.0392 &      0.082398 &             0.329091 &        0.04414 &             0.028872 &        0.0255 \\
52.0  &             0.024 &                0.096 &                     0.2016 &                         0.096 &                     0.024 &                0.0384 &      0.084013 &             0.335543 &       0.045005 &             0.029438 &         0.026 \\
53.0  &            0.0235 &                0.094 &                     0.1974 &                         0.094 &                    0.0235 &                0.0376 &      0.085629 &             0.341996 &       0.045871 &             0.030004 &        0.0265 \\
54.0  &             0.023 &                0.092 &                     0.1932 &                         0.092 &                     0.023 &                0.0368 &      0.087245 &             0.348449 &       0.046736 &              0.03057 &         0.027 \\
55.0  &            0.0225 &                 0.09 &                      0.189 &                          0.09 &                    0.0225 &                 0.036 &       0.08886 &             0.354902 &       0.047602 &             0.031136 &        0.0275 \\
56.0  &             0.022 &                0.088 &                     0.1848 &                         0.088 &                     0.022 &                0.0352 &      0.090476 &             0.361354 &       0.048467 &             0.031703 &         0.028 \\
57.0  &            0.0215 &                0.086 &                     0.1806 &                         0.086 &                    0.0215 &                0.0344 &      0.092092 &             0.367807 &       0.049333 &             0.032269 &        0.0285 \\
58.0  &             0.021 &                0.084 &                     0.1764 &                         0.084 &                     0.021 &                0.0336 &      0.093707 &              0.37426 &       0.050198 &             0.032835 &         0.029 \\
59.0  &            0.0205 &                0.082 &                     0.1722 &                         0.082 &                    0.0205 &                0.0328 &      0.095323 &             0.380713 &       0.051064 &             0.033401 &        0.0295 \\
60.0  &              0.02 &                 0.08 &                      0.168 &                          0.08 &                      0.02 &                 0.032 &      0.096939 &             0.387165 &       0.051929 &             0.033967 &          0.03 \\
61.0  &            0.0195 &                0.078 &                     0.1638 &                         0.078 &                    0.0195 &                0.0312 &      0.098554 &             0.393618 &       0.052795 &             0.034533 &        0.0305 \\
62.0  &             0.019 &                0.076 &                     0.1596 &                         0.076 &                     0.019 &                0.0304 &       0.10017 &             0.400071 &        0.05366 &             0.035099 &         0.031 \\
63.0  &            0.0185 &                0.074 &                     0.1554 &                         0.074 &                    0.0185 &                0.0296 &      0.101785 &             0.406524 &       0.054526 &             0.035665 &        0.0315 \\
64.0  &             0.018 &                0.072 &                     0.1512 &                         0.072 &                     0.018 &                0.0288 &      0.103401 &             0.412976 &       0.055391 &             0.036231 &         0.032 \\
65.0  &            0.0175 &                 0.07 &                      0.147 &                          0.07 &                    0.0175 &                 0.028 &      0.105017 &             0.419429 &       0.056257 &             0.036798 &        0.0325 \\
66.0  &             0.017 &                0.068 &                     0.1428 &                         0.068 &                     0.017 &                0.0272 &      0.106632 &             0.425882 &       0.057122 &             0.037364 &         0.033 \\
67.0  &            0.0165 &                0.066 &                     0.1386 &                         0.066 &                    0.0165 &                0.0264 &      0.108248 &             0.432335 &       0.057988 &              0.03793 &        0.0335 \\
68.0  &             0.016 &                0.064 &                     0.1344 &                         0.064 &                     0.016 &                0.0256 &      0.109864 &             0.438787 &       0.058853 &             0.038496 &         0.034 \\
69.0  &            0.0155 &                0.062 &                     0.1302 &                         0.062 &                    0.0155 &                0.0248 &      0.111479 &              0.44524 &       0.059718 &             0.039062 &        0.0345 \\
70.0  &             0.015 &                 0.06 &                      0.126 &                          0.06 &                     0.015 &                 0.024 &      0.113095 &             0.451693 &       0.060584 &             0.039628 &         0.035 \\
71.0  &            0.0145 &                0.058 &                     0.1218 &                         0.058 &                    0.0145 &                0.0232 &      0.114711 &             0.458146 &       0.061449 &             0.040194 &        0.0355 \\
72.0  &             0.014 &                0.056 &                     0.1176 &                         0.056 &                     0.014 &                0.0224 &      0.116326 &             0.464598 &       0.062315 &              0.04076 &         0.036 \\
73.0  &            0.0135 &                0.054 &                     0.1134 &                         0.054 &                    0.0135 &                0.0216 &      0.117942 &             0.471051 &        0.06318 &             0.041327 &        0.0365 \\
74.0  &             0.013 &                0.052 &                     0.1092 &                         0.052 &                     0.013 &                0.0208 &      0.119558 &             0.477504 &       0.064046 &             0.041893 &         0.037 \\
75.0  &            0.0125 &                 0.05 &                      0.105 &                          0.05 &                    0.0125 &                  0.02 &      0.121173 &             0.483957 &       0.064911 &             0.042459 &        0.0375 \\
76.0  &             0.012 &                0.048 &                     0.1008 &                         0.048 &                     0.012 &                0.0192 &      0.122789 &             0.490409 &       0.065777 &             0.043025 &         0.038 \\
77.0  &            0.0115 &                0.046 &                     0.0966 &                         0.046 &                    0.0115 &                0.0184 &      0.124404 &             0.496862 &       0.066642 &             0.043591 &        0.0385 \\
78.0  &             0.011 &                0.044 &                     0.0924 &                         0.044 &                     0.011 &                0.0176 &       0.12602 &             0.503315 &       0.067508 &             0.044157 &         0.039 \\
79.0  &            0.0105 &                0.042 &                     0.0882 &                         0.042 &                    0.0105 &                0.0168 &      0.127636 &             0.509768 &       0.068373 &             0.044723 &        0.0395 \\
80.0  &              0.01 &                 0.04 &                      0.084 &                          0.04 &                      0.01 &                 0.016 &      0.129251 &              0.51622 &       0.069239 &             0.045289 &          0.04 \\
81.0  &            0.0095 &                0.038 &                     0.0798 &                         0.038 &                    0.0095 &                0.0152 &      0.130867 &             0.522673 &       0.070104 &             0.045855 &        0.0405 \\
82.0  &             0.009 &                0.036 &                     0.0756 &                         0.036 &                     0.009 &                0.0144 &      0.132483 &             0.529126 &        0.07097 &             0.046422 &         0.041 \\
83.0  &            0.0085 &                0.034 &                     0.0714 &                         0.034 &                    0.0085 &                0.0136 &      0.134098 &             0.535579 &       0.071835 &             0.046988 &        0.0415 \\
84.0  &             0.008 &                0.032 &                     0.0672 &                         0.032 &                     0.008 &                0.0128 &      0.135714 &             0.542031 &       0.072701 &             0.047554 &         0.042 \\
85.0  &            0.0075 &                 0.03 &                      0.063 &                          0.03 &                    0.0075 &                 0.012 &       0.13733 &             0.548484 &       0.073566 &              0.04812 &        0.0425 \\
86.0  &             0.007 &                0.028 &                     0.0588 &                         0.028 &                     0.007 &                0.0112 &      0.138945 &             0.554937 &       0.074432 &             0.048686 &         0.043 \\
87.0  &            0.0065 &                0.026 &                     0.0546 &                         0.026 &                    0.0065 &                0.0104 &      0.140561 &              0.56139 &       0.075297 &             0.049252 &        0.0435 \\
88.0  &             0.006 &                0.024 &                     0.0504 &                         0.024 &                     0.006 &                0.0096 &      0.142177 &             0.567842 &       0.076163 &             0.049818 &         0.044 \\
89.0  &            0.0055 &                0.022 &                     0.0462 &                         0.022 &                    0.0055 &                0.0088 &      0.143792 &             0.574295 &       0.077028 &             0.050384 &        0.0445 \\
90.0  &             0.005 &                 0.02 &                      0.042 &                          0.02 &                     0.005 &                 0.008 &      0.145408 &             0.580748 &       0.077894 &              0.05095 &         0.045 \\
91.0  &            0.0045 &                0.018 &                     0.0378 &                         0.018 &                    0.0045 &                0.0072 &      0.147023 &             0.587201 &       0.078759 &             0.051517 &        0.0455 \\
92.0  &             0.004 &                0.016 &                     0.0336 &                         0.016 &                     0.004 &                0.0064 &      0.148639 &             0.593653 &       0.079625 &             0.052083 &         0.046 \\
93.0  &            0.0035 &                0.014 &                     0.0294 &                         0.014 &                    0.0035 &                0.0056 &      0.150255 &             0.600106 &        0.08049 &             0.052649 &        0.0465 \\
94.0  &             0.003 &                0.012 &                     0.0252 &                         0.012 &                     0.003 &                0.0048 &       0.15187 &             0.606559 &       0.081356 &             0.053215 &         0.047 \\
95.0  &            0.0025 &                 0.01 &                      0.021 &                          0.01 &                    0.0025 &                 0.004 &      0.153486 &             0.613012 &       0.082221 &             0.053781 &        0.0475 \\
96.0  &             0.002 &                0.008 &                     0.0168 &                         0.008 &                     0.002 &                0.0032 &      0.155102 &             0.619465 &       0.083087 &             0.054347 &         0.048 \\
97.0  &            0.0015 &                0.006 &                     0.0126 &                         0.006 &                    0.0015 &                0.0024 &      0.156717 &             0.625917 &       0.083952 &             0.054913 &        0.0485 \\
98.0  &             0.001 &                0.004 &                     0.0084 &                         0.004 &                     0.001 &                0.0016 &      0.158333 &              0.63237 &       0.084818 &             0.055479 &         0.049 \\
99.0  &            0.0005 &                0.002 &                     0.0042 &                         0.002 &                    0.0005 &                0.0008 &      0.159949 &             0.638823 &       0.085683 &             0.056046 &        0.0495 \\
100.0 &               0.0 &                  0.0 &                        0.0 &                           0.0 &                       0.0 &                   0.0 &      0.161564 &             0.645276 &       0.086549 &             0.056612 &          0.05 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]