# Longtable wider than textwidth

Tags: tables, positioning, longtable, text

Assuming I have a table going over several pages

```
\documentclass[DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,longtable}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Create a very compact itemized list environment
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet, nosep, wide, 
                 leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
                 before=\vspace{-0.50\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

% keep scope of longtable-related instructions local to current TeX group
\begingroup 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <--- important
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}P{0.38}P{0.38}P{0.2}}

\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}\\ 
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{l}{(Table \ref{my-label}, cont'd)}\\ % re-state table number
\addlinespace
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{r}{(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\begin{mylist}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

%\addlinespace % omit if at page break

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\end{longtable}
\endgroup % end of TeX group that encases the 'longtable' material

\end{document}
```

Code Copy and pasted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414342/make-text-readable-in-table-needed-automatic-text-wrapping-in-list-like-enviro?answertab=votes#tab-top), thanks to [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico).

I need the table to be wider than my textwidth - in portraitmode. Using the `geometry` package as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414935/make-longtable-in-landscape-mode-wider-than-textwidth) is unfeasable because than the table starts on a new page. I want to have it within my textflow though. Is there a way to make a longtable wider than the textiwdth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the values of \LTleft and \LTright: for instance,

```
\setlength\LTleft{-40pt}
\setlength\LTright{-40pt}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and Easy. I accept this answer. Is there a quick and easy way to do that with a `tabularx` too?
`\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}  LLLLL @{}}
%CONTENT
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}`? Writing `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth+80pt}{@{}  LLLLL @{}}` does not do the trick

Comment: For tabularx, you can use the `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`). In case you use `\ltables` (which combines `longtable` and `tabularx`), the above parameters might work, but I've never tested.

Comment: Would using `changepage` not signify that the table starts on a new page and come "out of the text flow"?

Comment: Not at all (except perhaps the automatic placement of tables by LaTeX).

Answer (score 0):

Use package `xltabular` with the environment of the same name:

```
\documentclass[DIV=8,captions=tableabove]{scrartcl}
[...]
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,xltabular}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1\textwidth}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet, nosep, wide, 
    leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
    before=\vspace{-0.50\baselineskip},
    after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

\begingroup 
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}       
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}X >{\RaggedRight}X P{0.22} @{} }
        \caption{My caption} \label{my-label}\\ 
        \toprule
...
```

[image]