# Make caption as wide as (long)table

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, width, text

Assuming I have a table going over several pages

```
\documentclass[DIV=8]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,ragged2e,longtable}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%% Create a very compact itemized list environment
\newlist{mylist}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{label=\textbullet, nosep, wide, 
                 leftmargin=*, % hanging indentation
                 before=\vspace{-0.50\baselineskip},
                 after =\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}

% keep scope of longtable-related instructions local to current TeX group
\begingroup 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <--- important
\setlength\LTleft{-40pt}
\setlength\LTright{-40pt}

\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}P{0.38}P{0.38}P{0.2}}

\caption{Loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong Caption} \label{my-label}\\ 
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{l}{(Table \ref{my-label}, cont'd)}\\ % re-state table number
\addlinespace
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{r}{(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\begin{mylist}
     \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\addlinespace

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

%\addlinespace % omit if at page break

\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing  
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing 
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} & 
\begin{mylist}
    \item Lorem ipsum
    \item Lorem ipsum
\end{mylist} \\ 

\end{longtable}
\endgroup % end of TeX group that encases the 'longtable' material

\end{document}
```

Code Copy and pasted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414342/make-text-readable-in-table-needed-automatic-text-wrapping-in-list-like-enviro?answertab=votes#tab-top), thanks to [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico).

I need the caption to be as wide as my table (-40pt left and right of `textwidth`). Right now, it is as wide as the text in my document.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the link. How would I add `\textwidth+80pt` in this example? Something like `\captionsetup{width=\textwidth+80pt}` is not working... But I need to use `.pt` ontop of my `\textwidth`.

Comment: If you include the `calc` package, your `captionsetup` works fine.